# Anchoring nav toggle to the right and styling toggle button

Tags: html, css, toggle, nav, responsive

I'm working on creating a responsive nav toggle but I am having trouble with aligning my menu to the right. I tried using position:absolute because I want it on top of my main content.

Also, is there a way to target CSS styling to "Menu"?

```
<nav class="nav-collapse">
    <ul>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">A</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">C</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">D</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">E</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">F</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">G</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div>
        <a class="btn-grn" href="">A</a>
        <a class="btn-vio" href="">B</a>
        <a class="btn-grn">C</a>
    </div>
</nav>

<script>
  var navigation = responsiveNav(".nav-collapse");
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/f298xtz6/